# PCB footprint shows blank when importing components to ALtium17

Tags: altium

I used UltraLibrarian to download schematics and footprints to Altium17. I downloaded the zip file for L7805 regulator, followed every step mentioned in the
[tutorial](https://app.ultralibrarian.com/content/help/?altium_designer.htm)

The schematic get imported properly, but when I open the PCB footprint, it is blank. Just a gray space and nothing else. I am so confused. I noted this when I tried to import models from the component search engine also. The schematic gets imported, but the PCB footprint is just blank. Can someone please help me to figure out what is happening?

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot of what you are seeing? I have never had good success with UltraLibrarian, I much prefer to make my own libraries

Comment: Hard to tell just from your description, but are all your layers visible if you look in the View Configuration ? Also I assume you have toggled through Shift+S to make sure its not just a visibility setting? Does anything show up if you press 3 to enter 3D view?